# Spring Mongo DB Query (if id is not null)

Tags: spring, mongodb

I developpemnt on spring projects. I'm using mongodb and spring data.

I need to support.

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("owner.$id").is(user.getId()).( and("idea.$id").is(null));)
```

i want  that `("idea.$id").is( not null)`

How can i do?

Answer (score 16):

You are looking for **[`$ne`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html#ne-java.lang.Object-)** operator.

```
(and("idea.$id").ne(null))
```

Comment: I kept looking for a method called notNull(...) in the auto complete suggestions, but didn't think about ne....
Thanks to this blog, the mystery was solved :)